# How does one speed up python programs in turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *
import time
ht()
setup(width=500, height=500, startx=0, starty=0)
x=0
y=0
goto(0, 0)
colormode(255)
while True:
    write("Please type your screens size in pixels into the console.", move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", 10, "normal"))
    x = int(input('x'))
    y = int(input('y'))
    if x > 0:
        print('.')
    if y > 0:
        print('...')
        break
    if x==0:
        x=1000
        y=500
        break
    else:
        clear()
        write("Please enter a valid number (ie. x, y)", move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", 28, "normal"))    
setup(width=1400, height=800, startx=100, starty=20)
clear()
def FADE_IN_OUT(arg, align, font, size, Norm, fspeedin, fspeedout, pause):
    r=255
    g=255
    b=255
    for i in range(51):
        pencolor((r,g,b))
        write(arg, move=False, align=align, font=(font, size, Norm))
        r-=5
        g-=5
        b-=5
        time.sleep(fspeedin/51)
    time.sleep(pause)
    clear()
    for i in range(51):
        clear()
        pencolor((r,g,b))
        write(arg, move=False, align=align, font=(font, size, Norm))
        r+=5
        g+=5
        b+=5
        time.sleep(fspeedout/51)

FADE_IN_OUT("47 Studios", "center", "Arial", x//5, "normal", 2.5, 2.5, 5)
```

I was wondering how I could speed up this program from taking a minute or two to do to taking 10 seconds, I'm sure that this is a very simple problem and I am just being stupid but I am new to programs that are more fast paced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase how fast the turtle draws things by setting `turtle.speed`

`0` is the fastest. So, you can set `turtle.speed(0)` to have the turtle draw things at the fastest speed.

Or, since you've imported everything `speed(0)`

Straight from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.speed)

Comment: the point of the question was to find out how I could make it happen in ten seconds with or without the time.sleep

Comment: I thought you said time.sleep to 0

Comment: Btw it still takes a minute or two but it is a lot faster